# Error: encfs has been disabled because it requires FUSE

Tags: encfs

I'm trying to install and run command in macOS Catalina 10.15.7: brew install encfs
but getting error below
Error: encfs has been disabled because it requires FUSE!
or
Error: homebrew/fuse was deprecated. This tap is now empty and all its contents were either deleted or migrated.